# How Can I add date published meta tag in Mediawiki CMS?

Tags: php, facebook, content-management-system, wikipedia, wikimedia

I have installed Mediawiki `SEO` extension. To add meta tag in head section they have the syntax something like that given below, but can't add date published meta tag.

```
{{#seo:
    |title={{#if: {{{page_title|}}} | {{{page_title}}} | Welcome to WikiSEO}}
    |titlemode={{{title_mode|}}}
    |keywords={{{keywords|}}}
    |description={{{description|}}}
    |google-site-verification= dnweo23234k23exn23lx23xn23n
    |fb:app_id= 1232425634
    |fb:admins= Mehrab Tamim
    |date-published= ????which value should put here
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no meta tag which provides the function you search. OpenGraph has a property called [`article:published_time`](http://ogp.me/#type_article) with which you can provide the publication date of an article on the website, but natively the MediaWiki SEO extension doesn't support this tag, as you can read in it's [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiSEO). This means you have to add the tag manually.

To add this tag (is is btw. **untested**!), open the file **WikiSEO.body.php** and add a new value to the `WikiSEO::$valid_params`-array, called `article:published_time`. Then add a new index called `article:published_time` with the value `property` to the `WikiSEO::$tag_types`-array and you should be good to go.

Small example:

```
protected static $valid_params = [
     // other entries
     "article:published_time",
];

protected static $_tag_types = [
     // other entries
     "article:published_time" => "property",
];
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I got it at last. But how can I call the new page published date and existing page modified date in this meta tag?

Comment: You can try do something with the [`{{REVISIONTIMESTAMP}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#REVISIONTIMESTAMP) magic word of MediaWiki. Otherwise you have either to set the dates manually or change the [`modifyHTML()`](https://github.com/tinymighty/wiki-seo/blob/master/WikiSEO.body.php#L251)-method of the `WikiSEO` class.